# Join a table onto itself

Tags: max, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, self-join

I have a table like this where TIMELINE is just an overall series of dates in order and DATE that I've matched to the dates in TIMELINE and contains actual records of dates that have values (shown in the NUMBER  column)

| TIMELINE | DATE | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 | 2022-03-03 | NULL |
| 2022-03-04 | 2022-03-04 | 40 |
| 2022-03-07 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-03-08 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-06-08 | 2022-06-08 | 45 |
| 2022-06-28 | 2022-06-28 | NULL |
| 2022-06-29 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-06-30 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-07-08 | 2022-07-08 | 80 |

I am trying to fill in this table so that for every DATE that is NULL, its NUMBER becomes the value of the most recent/max DATE that is <= to the current date of the row I am looking at. So for example, in the third row, the DATE is NULL so its NUMBER would become the value (40) that is associated with the date 2022-03-04 and the same thing for fourth row. Then for the third to last and the second to last row, its NUMBER would be NULL because that is the value associated with the most recent date before that row.

I am trying to get an output like this:

| TIMELINE | DATE | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 | 2022-03-03 | NULL |
| 2022-03-04 | 2022-03-04 | 40 |
| 2022-03-07 | NULL | 40 |
| 2022-03-08 | NULL | 40 |
| 2022-06-08 | 2022-06-08 | 45 |
| 2022-06-28 | 2022-06-28 | NULL |
| 2022-06-29 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-06-30 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-07-08 | 2022-07-08 | 80 |

Would this be achieved by joining the table onto itself?/Is there a function that would help me do this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, joining the table with an alias of itself would allow you to do a join to itself to obtain the desired value that's not null in the second table when the value in the primary table is null.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can join them in this way?

Comment: Would it be something like ```SELECT * from TABLE_1 A left join TABLE_1 B where A.DATE IS NULL AND MAX(B.DATE) <= A.DATE ;``` ?

Comment: Yes, but a little more involved if you want to update a table based on another table.  The first thing I would recommend is changing your column names here to use something other than reserved words like DATE and NUMBER.  If I get some free time later this afternoon I can draft the query for you.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update.html

Comment: I am using multiple CTEs to create the table in my example, am I able to use UPDATE in its own CTE ? Otherwise I'm not sure if I would be able to use that command

Comment: See below - update done using a single update statement with an inline table.  No need for CTEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the update query that would produce the desired results.  Although I've used your reserved words, I would suggest avoiding those in your modeling.

```
--
-- Create test table
--
create
or replace table x (timeline date, date date, number integer);

--
-- load test data
--
insert into
    x
values
    ('2022-03-03'::date,'2022-03-03'::date,NULL), ('2022-03-04'::date,'2022-03-04'::date,40), ('2022-03-07'::date,NULL,NULL), ('2022-03-08'::date,NULL,NULL), ('2022-06-08'::date,'2022-06-08'::date,45),('2022-06-28'::date,'2022-06-28'::date,NULL), ('2022-06-29'::date,NULL,NULL), ('2022-06-30'::date,NULL,NULL), ('2022-07-08'::date,'2022-07-08'::date,80);
    
    --
    -- Update the original table via a correlation
    --

update
    x
set
    x.number = z.number
from
    (
        select
            a.timeline,
            a.date,
            case
                when (a.date is NULL) then b.number
                else a.number
            end number
        from
            x a
            left join x b on b.timeline = (
                select
                    max(timeline)
                from
                    x
                where
                    timeline < a.timeline
                    and date is not null
            )
    ) z
where
    x.timeline = z.timeline
    and x.date = z.date;
    
    --
    -- Results
    --
    select * from x order by 1;
```

Results:

```
TIMELINE    DATE        NUMBER
2022-03-03  2022-03-03  
2022-03-04  2022-03-04  40
2022-03-07              40
2022-03-08              40
2022-06-08  2022-06-08  45
2022-06-28  2022-06-28  
2022-06-29      
2022-06-30      
2022-07-08  2022-07-08  80
```